# Date range selector on highstock is separate container?

Tags: render, highcharts, date-range

Is this possible to split data range selector and chart on highstock?
In other words is this possible to render chart to different container than date range selector?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible, but what it is your goal / target?

Comment: update separate chart using daterange selector of other